# Integrating Spring Security with AWS Cognito

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jwt, amazon-cognito

I'm building the backend for a system which uses AWS Cognito in a Spring Boot project. For some of my API requests, I want them to be authenticated using a bearer token the client passes with the AWS Cognito user's JWT.

I have the following class to validate and parse it:

```java
public class Auth {
    record CanonicalAuthToken(String token, UUID uuid, String username) {}

    public static Optional<CanonicalAuthToken> validateAndExtractToken(String token, String jwksUrl, String jwtTokenIssuer) {
        var decodedJwtToken = JWT.decode(token);
        var kid = decodedJwtToken.getKeyId();

        try {

            var http = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL(jwksUrl));
            // Let's cache the result from Cognito for the default of 10 hours
            var provider = new GuavaCachedJwkProvider(http);

            var jwk = provider.get(kid);

            var algorithm = com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
            var verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                    .withIssuer(jwtTokenIssuer)
                    .build();

            var decoded = verifier.verify(token);

            return Optional.of(new CanonicalAuthToken(decoded.getToken(), UUID.fromString(decoded.getSubject()), decoded.getClaim("username").asString()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private Auth() {}
}
```

However, this really only works when manually calling it within the body of each endpoint implementation. Instead, I want to take advantage of Spring's built-in Security mechanism to act as middleware for the authentication.

I did find several solutions, all of which include about half a dozen classes. However, none of these allow me to actually access the decoded JWT in the endpoint implementation itself (specifically, I want to access the `sub` field so that I can access the user's UUID and match it in the database).

All the resources I've been able to find so far are somewhat relevant and helpful, however I still can't find a way to accomplish this specific goal and I'm not really sure what to even Google.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should configure Filter and send the token in the header from the FE. Once you have the token in the filter you can parse and validate

```
 @Override
    public void doFilter(
      ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        // validate and parse token
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        LOG.info(
          "Logging Request  {} : {}", req.getMethod(), 
          req.getRequestURI());
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        LOG.info(
          "Logging Response :{}", 
          res.getContentType());
    }
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter

https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture